# Theorem hunt linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Apparently a Theorem exists that says: the rank of a linear map coincides with the rank of any of its matrix representations.

Context is from this question 
[Making matrices look the same w.r.t different basis's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642237/making-matrices-look-the-same-w-r-t-different-basiss)

i am looking for said theorem and preferably a proof of it, i tried to prove the result on my own but im apparently to braindead atm to do so.

Comment: Which definition of rank are you using? One way of defining it is as the dimension of the column space; but this is just saying that it's the dimension of the range of the linear map, and clearly this will be invariant among our matrix representations (i.e. doesn't depend on our choice of bases of the source and target spaces). On the other hand, other definitions of rank might make that connection less obvious.

Comment: Def'n rank: the rank of a matrix $ A\in \Bbb F^{m,n} $ is the column rank of A. Def'n Dimension of range of T equals column rank of $\mathcal M (T) $ Def'n the column rank of A is the dimension of the span of the columns of A in $ \Bbb F^{m,1} $

Comment: I found it and your correct if you wanna post as solution ill accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\varphi: V\to W$ is a linear map, where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces. Suppose $(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n)$ and $(\mathbf{w}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{w}_m)$ are ordered bases for $V$ and $W$, respectively, giving rise to a matrix representation $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$ of $\varphi$.

By definition, $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A})$ is the column rank of $\mathbf{A}$, i.e. the dimension of the linear span of the columns of $\mathbf{A}$, call them $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_n$. But
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{a}_1 \mathbf{v}(1) + \cdots + \mathbf{a}_n \mathbf{v}(n)$$
shows that in fact the linear span of $\{\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_n\}$ is the image of $\mathbb{F}^n \cong V$ under the map $\mathbf{A}$ (i.e. multiplication by $\mathbf{A}$ on the left).

The isomorphism $W \cong \mathbb{F}^m$ given by the ordered basis above provides, upon restriction, an isomorphism between the image of $\mathbf{A}$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^m$) and the image of $\varphi$ (as a subspace of $W$).

In particular, the dimension of the image of $\mathbf{A}$ and the dimension of the image of $\varphi$ are exactly the same. But the former was $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A})$, so 
$$\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}) = \dim \varphi[V]$$
This was independent of the choice of ordered bases for $V$ and $W$, so it follows that
$$\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}) = \dim \varphi[V] = \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B})$$
for any matrix representations $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}$ of $\varphi$.